# Generating WADL request parameters for @InjectParam

Tags: rest, jersey, jax-rs, wadl

I am using the [@InjectParam](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.12/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/core/InjectParam.html) to inject query parameters into a JAX-RS resource that contains @QueryParam annotated fields on a Jersey 1.12 implementation.

On the Resource:

```
@Path("query")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Query queryParam(@InjectParam Query query) {
    return query;
}
```

And in the pojo that receives the injected parameters I have some JAXB and JAX-RS annotations.

```
 @XmlRootElement
 public class Query {
    @QueryParam("value1")
    String value1;
 }
```

A simple test from a REST client:

> http://localhost:8888/sandbox/query?value1=hello3

Produces the correct results:

```
<query>
  <value1>hello3</value1>
</query>
```

That's great, but I also use the [wadl-maven-plugin](http://wadl.java.net/wadl2java.html) to generate a client which uses the WADL file to produce client code.  The WADL file does not include the necessary [request parameters](http://www.w3.org/Submission/wadl/#x3-190002.9.1) that would be there if the @QueryParam annotation was included in the resource method parameters.  Subsequently my client is produced to accept no parameters:

```
SandboxApi.sandbox().query().getAsQuery()
```

instead of accepting a populated generated client pojo.

```
Query queryClient = new Query();
queryClient.setValue1("hello3");
SandboxApi.sandbox().query().getAsQuery(queryClient);
```

Anyone know of a magic annotation I can put on the Jersey Resource that will produce a WADL with the right information so Wadl2Java could generate a client that will accept the POJO and subsequently send the appropriate fields as query parameters?

Answer (score 0):

A response provided (via a private conversation) from some of the fine people working on Jersey:

```
@Path("query")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Query queryParam(@QueryParam("value1") String value1, 
                        @InjectParam Query query) {
   return query; 
}
```

query param "value1" should appear in generated WADL.

In-built WADL generator does not contain support for these cases and I'm not sure whether it will be supported anytime soon.

Comment: This does work, but the disadvantage is that the dummy parameters (value1) would be confusing to developers because they are never used.  Also, the client then must transfer the values from the POJO to the method call manually:  Query actual = SandboxApi.sandbox().query().getAsQuery(expected.value1);